# How to get 3 inputs in one variables using class method

Tags: python, class, variables, input

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, chemistry, english, math):
        self.chemistry = chemistry
        self.english = english
        self.math = math

    def chemistry(self):
        return self.chemistry

    def english(self):
        return self.english

    def math(self):
        return self.math

    def tot(self):
        return self.chemistry + self.english + self.math

answer = Student(100,20,30)
answer.tot()
print(answer.tot())
```

I want to know how to get 3 inputs in one variable. I've tried using "list" but it didn't work.

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: What happens when you have a member function and an attribute with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

You can use a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) or [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) as one variable, for example with a function called `add` (adds two numbers):

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

print(add(3, 8))


def add(nums):
    return nums[0] + nums[1]

print(add([3,8])) # List
print(add((3,8))) # Tuple
```

#### Code:

For class:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, subjects):
        self.chemistry = subjects[0]
        self.english = subjects[1]
        self.math = subjects[2]

    # Your Methods, consider renaming them
```

For initializing class:

```
answer = Student([100,20,30]) # Using a List
answer = Student((100,20,30)) # Using a Tuple
```